# MVC 5.0 strange behavior

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, behavior

When I run this action every time it increases `rating.Likes`.
Can I have a little help?

```
public ActionResult Like(int id)
{
    ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
    var rating = db.Ratings.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id);

    if (!(rating.RatedFrom.Contains(User.Identity.Name)))
    {
        rating.Likes++;
        rating.RatedFrom.Add(User.Identity.Name); 
    }

    rating.Views--;
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Details", db.ImageModels.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == id));
}
```

Comment: Whats RatedFrom? String?

Comment: why wouldn't it? you're telling it to increase, and then saving the changes. what would you expect?

Comment: @DLeh I think that what he said was that It's increasing even if the user already is in the RatedFrom. What we need to know is: What is RatedFrom, maybe this is not mapped to anything, and the user name never has been saved.

Comment: @Fals RatedFrom is List<string>

Comment: @DimoChanev Then It's not mapped to nothing. This user names are not getting saved to the data base.

Comment: @Fals how can i fix this?

Comment: RatedFrom should be an entity, with an Id and the UserName

Comment: @Fals RatedFrom must have property id or its elements must have properiy id or the both?

Comment: You should provide an Id and the Propertie UserName for this entity.

Comment: @Fals can you give an example, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Create the `RatedFrom` class:**

```
public class RatedFrom
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string UserName {get; set;}
    public DateTime RatedDate {get; set;}
    /*Other properties*/
}
```

**2) Setup the `RatedFrom` at your `Ratings`**

```
public class Rating 
{
    /*Other properties*/

    public virtual ICollection<RatedFrom> RatedFromList {get; set;}

    public Rating()
    {
        /*Other properties initialization*/
        RatedFromList = new List<RatedFrom>();
    }
}
```

**3) Setup the `RatedFrom` at you `DbContext` to be mapped to the Data Base:**

```
public DbSet<RatedFrom> RatedFrom { get; set; }
```

**4) Change the Controller code:**

```
if (!(rating.RatedFromList.Where(x=> x.UserName == User.Identity.Name).Count() > 0))
{
    rating.Likes++;
    rating.RatedFrom.Add(new RatedFrom {  UserName = User.Identity.Name }); 
}
```

And done! Given that you are using Coding-First. If you are using Database-first you must create the class mapp manually: [Mapping to Existing Table in the Database](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/661053/Entity-Framework-Code-First-Map)